# Why onedrive acts as if my stuff are in conflict?

Tags: boot, onedrive

I got a folder in both computers. In one computer it's modified at 8/18. In other computer it's modified at 8/27

Only one of them is modified. So I installed onedrive after 8/18

Yet this is the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The icon with the two arrows mean the folder has not completely synced with the cloud.

- Cut and paste that folder to a location that OneDrive does not handle.
- Wait 10 seconds
- Cut and paste that same folder back to OneDrive

This may resync the folder correctly this time.

OneDrive has a lot of bugs. This is one of them.